# Sorry to hear you leave or leaving?

Tags: tenses, present-tense

Simple question - the context is having user of your app unsubscribing. Would you say

**We're sorry to hear you leave**

or

**We're sorry to hear you leaving**

I was thinking of first options because it mentions action that's already been done (but still happened in present if that makes sense).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Sorry to hear [that] you are leaving". ('That' can be omitted in informal speech.) Your examples sound as though you can literally hear the person walking away.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.

The correct form would be "we're sorry to hear you are leaving" or "we're sorry to hear that you are are leaving". However, it would be more idiomatic to say "We're sorry to see you go" than use either of these forms.

Comment: Another option, which also allows for the present simple to be used, is "We're sorry to see you leave".

Comment: Although mistake on my part, in my original text there is " We're " already for some reason I didn't mention it